# Accessing the public class variable from another class in same directory

Tags: java, class, variables

I've come across a java code in which the method `aw_best_tour_index()` of public class Utilities access the variable of the class `InOut` which is `public`. The variables of the class `InOut` are `best_in_try` and `max_index`. They've been called in the method like this:

`final int[] values = InOut.best_in_try;` and

`final int l =  InOut.maxindex;` .

But when I compile this using javac in command prompt it shows the error "Cannot find symbol". What should be reason for this?

Comment: Are the fields static?

Comment: Cannot find *what* symbol? and 'in the same directory': do you mean in the same *package*?

Comment: Yes all the variables are static and both the classes are in same package. Cannot find symbol "InOut"

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple problems:

- Did you include InOut if it isn't in the same Java file
- Are the variables static
- If not, is InOut an instance of the class containing maxindex and best_in_try?

Comment: InOut is in same package and they are all static. No, InOut is not an instance of the class.